# Applying QPropertyAnimation to QRect

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've created a QRect object

```
QRect ellipse(10.0 , 10.0 , 10.0 , 10.0);
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
painter.drawEllipse(ellipse);
```

Now I want to animate it using QPropertyAnimation, but since it can only be applied to QObject objects(as far as I get it), I need to somehow convert QRect into QObject. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You could explain me better what you want to do to give you another option.

Comment: I'm attempting to create the equalizer, based on float data array. I'm thinking of making circles instead of regular stripes and lines connecting them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a class, you can use your own widget, you must add a new property.

Example:

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QRect nrect READ nRect WRITE setNRect)

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

    QRect nRect() const;
    void setNRect(const QRect &rect);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:

    QRect mRect;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{

    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "nrect");
    //animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InBack);
    animation->setDuration(1000);
    animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 10, 10));
    animation->setEndValue(QRect(0, 0, 200, 200));
    animation->start();
    connect(animation, &QPropertyAnimation::valueChanged, [=](){
        update();
    });

}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}

QRect Widget::nRect() const
{
    return mRect;
}

void Widget::setNRect(const QRect &rect)
{
    mRect = rect;
}


void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event)
    QRect ellipse(mRect);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
    painter.drawEllipse(ellipse);
}
```

[code](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/RectAnimation)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for!